# Monitor disk I/O used by specific command

Tags: hard-drive, unix, time, benchmarking, io

I know that there are various tools for monitoring disk I/O, but I am wondering specifically if there is something equivalent to `time` for disk usage?  For example, I am benchmarking a specific command on different systems, and one of the metrics other than real-time and CPU-time I want to track is disk I/O. Meaning average write speed during the time the command was running.

Comment: the thing I am timing (using "time") is a python script. I am on a mac, but would like a solution that works in any *nix type environment.

Comment: yes - but I am hoping for something quite surgical. I am benchmarking with known file sizes, and timing the processes with the "time" command, so I could presume an average disk IO speed already. I would prefer however to have this reported in a way that is more accurate… i.e. is dividing my filesize by "real" time output of the time command actually an accurate portrayal of average IO speed utilized by my original command?

Comment: Dtrace scripts are a possible choice. iosnoop is one for example, that can monitor disk I/O on a per pid basis or per disk basis.  Dtrace is available for OSX, some Linux platforms  and Solaris.